# Zeroclipboard not copying on first Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I have the code and it is not working on first click, but on the second click it is working.

```
$("#btnCopiar").on("click",function(){
        var clipBoardObj = new ZeroClipboard($("#btnCopiar"), {
              moviePath: "../thirdparty/ZeroClipboard.swf"
        });;
        // Create your data here to copy to the clipboard and assign to a variable name data 
         var data =   "DATA IS COMING FROM SERVER OT TEXT INPUT";
                clipBoardObj.on("copy", function (event) {                  
                var clipboard = event.clipboardData;
                  clipboard.setData( "text/plain", data );
        });

    });

<button id="btnCopiar">Copiar</button>
```

Even if I have initialized the clipboard outside the click event, it is not working

Comment: Are you sure the button object exists in DOM before you add the listener to it?

Comment: YES Button exists in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this has to with the synchronous way you have written the code.

Your line `var data = ...` implies that the variable `data` is receiving its information from a call to the server that only happens right at that moment. *(I'm making some assumptions about code you have deleted in order to make the question more concise and understandable, though I could be wrong about that.)* That data is going to take a little while to arrive. However, immediately after that line you are using the `data` variable in the `clipBoardObj.on("copy", function(event) {...` function. The first time you run that function, the `data` will not yet have arrived. However, some time will elapse before the user clicks the button a second time. When that happens, there may have been enough time for the first call to the server to have returned, and `data` will have some data. Note, however, that the second time you run that function, it will only be using the `data` from the *first* call to the server, which may or may not be acceptable.